# how to add custom slider in magento2

Tags: magento2

I have bootstrap slider and I want to put it in magento2 can any one tell me how I do this

my code is below

```
js:bootstrap.js
js:bootstrap.min.js
```

Add code in requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        "jquery.bootstrap": "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min"
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery.bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel sli  de" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
     <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Mageplaza_HelloWorld::images/img.jpg'); ?>"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Mageplaza_HelloWorld::images/img-1.jpg'); ?>">
    </div>
  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs(['jquery', 'bootstrap' ],
      function ($, myslider) {
          $(document).ready(function(){

          });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Please create new question, I'm not able to ans here.

Comment: Please use <script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs(['jquery', 'bootstrap',  'bootstrap.min' ],
      function ($) {
          $(document).ready(function(){
                //your slider code
          });
      });
</script>